# Possible bad install of alsamixer utility

Tags: audio, hardware, alsa

Kernel version: 2.6.35.14 running (embedded) on an ARM MCIMX51. The system is rather outdated and old (ASoC). I am getting odd behavior with sound. I already defaulted asound config file (asound.play) with alsactl init and have managed to play some tone files I found (works). The speaker-test application runs but is not producing any sound (with no errors). A card is registered and things seem to be in order:

```
aplay -l:

card 0: ccwmx51p51 [ccwmx51p51], devie 0: WM8750 WM8750-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I wanted to use the alsamixer utility I found @ /usr/bin to see if it might be muted:

```
alsamixer
```

Running that command results in an error:

```
Error opening terminal: vt100.
```

I tried to Google that error but no luck (with respect to alsamixer or audio). Could someone explain what an error like this means, in general?

Comment: I guess you wanted to use `amixer` instead.

Comment: @CL I see your point (edited post to reflect that) but my question still remains. Shouldn't running alsamixer open up a user interface where I can toggle a mute/unmute function instead of producing an error message?

Comment: Yes, it should. But Google tells me your terminfo is not installed correctly.

Comment: @CL Any idea how to fix it? I found terminfo directory @ /usr/share

Comment: Ask whoever created and configured that system.